# Where is the API documentation for Windows LAPS?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-documentation

We want to integrate ServiceNow with Azure Active Directory. To do this, we would like to use API calls.
Microsoft published their LAPS PowerShell module with documentation about each function. PowerShell is however not the preferred option as it requires a MID server.

Checking the LAPS module I believe I found the URI to retrieve the LAPS AAD password from the LAPS.psm1 file:

```
beta/deviceLocalCredentials/{DeviceId}?$select=credentials
```

The other functions in this module are however written in assembly lapspsh.dll.

I am particularly interested in the functions: `Reset-LapsPassword` and `Set-LapsADPasswordExpirationTime`.

Does anybody have the URIs for them or some documentation about that?

Comment: I don't have any public docs to share, but `Reset-LapsPassword` simply calls `lapsutil!ResetPassword`, whereas `Set-LapsADPasswordExpirationTime` writes to the `msLAPS-PasswordExpirationTime` attribute on the computer account